# How to make recursive function, it needs to check if in a given string the current letter and the one next to it is either lowercase or upper case?

Tags: c++, c, recursion, uppercase, lowercase

It should convert a string like this: Example: **HEloOO**, should be converted into : **heLOoo** . For some reason it doesn't work,it just wont convert the letters from uppercase to lowercase and vice versa  any help would be appreciated ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void rek(char array[], int d)
{
    int counter=0;

    if(d==0)
    {
        printf("%s \n",array);
        printf("%d \n",counter);
    }
    else
    {
        if((array[d]>='A' && array[d]<='Z')&&(array[d-1]>='A' && array[d-1]<='Z'))
        {
            array[d]=array[d]+32;
            array[d-1]=array[d-1]+32;
            counter++;
            rek(array,d-2);
        }
        if((array[d]>='a' && array[d]<='z')&&(array[d-1]>='a' && array[d-1]<='z'))
        {
            array[d]=array[d]-32;
            array[d-1]=array[d-1]-32;
            counter++;
            rek(array,d-2);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    char array[100];
    int d;

    gets(array);
    d=strlen(array);

    rek(array,d);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This probably isn't the problem, but there is nothing in standard C or standard C++ that requires `array[d]>='A' && array[d]<='Z'` to do anything sensible. Use `std::isupper` and `std::islower`. Also read about `std::topper` and `std::tolower`.

Comment: Use a `printf` to show the value of `d`, `array[d]`, and `array[d-1]` at the beginning of the `rek` function and the problem should be obvious.

Comment: Also note that you're going to have a problem if `d` is ever an odd number, because the recursive call will never reach `0` in that case.

Comment: I don't know wheres the mistake, is it in the recursive call ?, also i how to make it work if {d} is odd number?

Comment: This is once more a question where "it doesn't work" is not enough. Please provide some input values, your expected output and the actual output of your program. Otherwise people will just be guessing (what you homework was?)

Comment: the function: `gets()` has been depreciated for years and is completely missing from the latest C standard (your compiler should have told you that)  Strongly suggest using `fgets()` instead of `gets()`

Answer (score 1):

Your function does not call itself when two adjacent characters have different cases. Also you can get different results when the string is processed from the start or from the end.

I would write the function the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char * rek(char *s)
{
    if (s[0] && s[1])
    {
        size_t i = 1;
        if (islower((unsigned char)s[0]) && islower((unsigned char)s[1]))
        {
            s[0] = toupper((unsigned char)s[0]);
            s[1] = toupper((unsigned char)s[1]);
            ++i;
        }
        else if (isupper((unsigned char)s[0]) && isupper((unsigned char)s[1]))
        {
            s[0] = tolower((unsigned char)s[0]);
            s[1] = tolower((unsigned char)s[1]);
            ++i;
        }

        rek(s + i);
    }

    return s;
}

int main( void )
{
    char s[] = "HEloOO";

    puts(rek(s));

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
heLOoo
```

Answer (score 0):

The *main* problem is that you recur *only* if your have a pair of upper-case or lower-case letters.  Otherwise, you drop off the end of your **if**, return to the calling program, and quit converting things.

The initial problem is that you've indexed your string with the length.  A string with 6 characters has indices 0-5, but you've started with locations 5 and 6 -- the final 'O' and the null character.

The result is that you check 'O' and '\0'; the latter isn't alphabetic at all, so you drop through all of your logic without doing anything, return to the main program, and finish.

For future reference, Here's the debugging instrumentation I used.  Also see the canonical SO [debug help](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>
void rek(char array[], int d)
{
    int counter=0;

    printf("ENTER rek %s %d\n", array, d);

    if(d==0)
    {
        printf("%s \n",array);
        printf("%d \n",counter);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("TRACE 1: %d %c%c\n", d, array[d-1], array[d]);
        if((array[d]>='A' && array[d]<='Z')&&(array[d-1]>='A' && array[d-1]<='Z'))
        {
            printf("TRACE 2: upper case");
            array[d]=array[d]+32;
            array[d-1]=array[d-1]+32;
            counter++;
            rek(array,d-2);
        }
        if((array[d]>='a' && array[d]<='z')&&(array[d-1]>='a' && array[d-1]<='z'))
        {
            printf("TRACE 3: lower case");
            array[d]=array[d]-32;
            array[d-1]=array[d-1]-32;
            counter++;
            rek(array,d-2);
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    char *array;
    int d;

    array = "HEloOO";
    d=strlen(array);

    rek(array,d);
    printf("%s\n", array);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot mate big help

Comment: You're welcome.  Remember to accept your favourite answer and up-vote the helpful comments.

Comment: Why use magic number 32?  Perhaps `array[d]=array[d]+32;` --> `array[d]=array[d] + ('a' - 'A');` which self documents more the intent.  To covert upper to lower, code could use `array[d] ^= 'a' & 'A';` which works for ASCII and EBCDIC.  Of course `tolower()` is quite standard.

Comment: Good point -- but please move the comment to the main body.  Down here, it's not going to get the notice it deserves.

Answer (score 0):

I come up with this dirty solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

string solve(const string& str)
{
    if (str.empty()) {
        return "";
    }
    if (str.front() >= 'a' && str.front() <= 'z') {
        return (char)toupper(str.front()) + solve(str.substr(1));
    }
    if (str.front() >= 'A' && str.front() <= 'Z') {
        return (char)tolower(str.front()) + solve(str.substr(1));
    }
}

int main()
{
    string str;
    cin >> str;
    cout << solve(str) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```